# How to find maximum between two numbers in javascript using switch case?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run with this code block but it does not work

```
Switch (num1>num2) {
case 0:
  document.write(num2);
  break;
case 1:
  document.write(num1);
 break;
}
```

Comment: num1>num2 can never match value of either of those cases

Comment: Your code is basically `document.write(Math.max(num1, num2))`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something simple as `Math.max(5, 10)`;

```js
const numOne = 5;
const numTwo = 10;

console.log(`Bigger number is: ${Math.max(numOne, numTwo)}`);
```

Or if you absolutely 'have to' use `switch statement`, you can try something like this:

```js
const numOne = 5;
const numTwo = 10;

switch(true) {
    case (numOne > numTwo):
        console.log(`Bigger number is ${numOne}`);
        break;
    case (numOne < numTwo):
        console.log(`Bigger number is ${numTwo}`);
        break;
    case (numOne === numTwo):
        console.log(`${numOne} is equal to ${numTwo}`);
        break;
     default: console.log(false, '-> Something went wrong');
}
```

Comment: Note backtick strings ("Template Literals") don't work in Internet Explorer https://caniuse.com/#search=template%20literals

Comment: Great, so don't use them, or better yet, don't use IE.
Nobody ever said anything about IE, but okay, instead of doing this:

` `Bigger number is ${numOne}` ` ... just do it the old way:

`console.log("Bigger number is:  " + numOne);`

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to template literals though

Answer (score 1):

Logical operations return boolean on Javascript.

document.write writes HTML expressions or JavaScript code to a document, console.log prints the result on the browser console.

```
   switch (num1>num2) {
      case true:
          console.log(num1);
       break;
       case false:
           console.log(num2);
       break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`switch` (with a lower case s) uses strict comparison `===` so the value of a boolean like `11 > 10` will never `===` `0` or `1`.

You need to test for the boolean if you want to do it this way:

```js
let num1 = 10
let num2 = 20

switch (num1>num2) {
    case false:
      console.log(num2);
      break;
    case true:
      console.log(num1);
     break;
    }
```

If for some reason you were given numbers you could explicitly cast them to booleans with something like `case !!0:` but that starts to get a little hard on the eyes.

If your goal is to find the max of two numbers, `Math.max(num1, num2)` is hard to beat for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You would just use the greater than / less than inside of the switch statement.

```js
var x = 10;
var y = 20;

switch(true) {
    case (x > y):
        console.log(x);
        break;
    case ( y > x):
        console.log(y);
        break;
}
```

Comment: if x == y then I think it wouldn't do any console log - the second case could be "default"

Comment: @LukeWenke his question did not ask about === though you could add another case. Also, the second should not be the default. What would happen if they were equal, that shouldn't render one larger than the other.

Comment: Normally the maximum function would still give an answer if both numbers are equal

Comment: I suggested the second could be "default" because it acts like an "else" (or x>y == false). If x>y is false it means y>=x.